# How to combine pagination with a criteria query in Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I use PagingAndSortingRepository and findAll(Pageable pageable) method to paging my data. I think that there is no way to provide any condition. For example sometime I want select and paging addresses where city=NY. Is there any way to provide condition and paging simultaneously?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `PagingAndSortingRepository` just adds the very basic CRUD methods in pagination mode. As the [reference documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.special-parameters) describes, you can simply add a `Pageable` parameter to any query method you define to achieve pagination of this query.

```
interface CustomerRepository implements Repository<Customer, Long> {

  Page<Customer> findByLastname(String lastname, Pageable pageable);

  List<Customer> findByFirstname(String firstname, Pageable pageable);
}
```

The first method will return a `Page` containing the page metadata like total elements available etc. To calculate this data it will trigger an additional count query for the query derived. The second query method returns the plain sliced result set without the count query being executed.

Comment: Hello @Olivier with the Pageagle i don't see where to specify the `offset`, `PageRequest` only accepts `page` and `size` . i don't really see why i have to do `page*size` to get my `offset`. is there any way to use `offset` as opposed to `page` ?

Comment: The reason `PageRequest` exposes `page` and `size` as only `offset` is not enough as you still need the `size`. The concept of pagination usually implies a page-centric view on data, which is what we express here. But nothing prevents you from coming up with your own implementation of `Pageable` that works with offsets and sizes.

Comment: How we can use Pagivation with Query API ?

Comment: Nice Explanation !!

Answer (score 4):

For Pagination you need 2 methods like getCount(Pageable pageable) and findAll(Pageable pageable)

Utilizing this functionality in Hibernate, however, is trivial. If you have any HQL query you can simply do this:

```
public Long getCount(Pageable pageable) {
    Query q = session.createQuery("Select count(t) From TableClass  t where t.city = 'NY'");
    Long cnt = (Long) q.uniqueResult();
    return cnt;
}

public List<TableClass> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
     Query q = session.createQuery("From TableClass  t where t.city = 'NY'");
     q.setFirstResult(start);
     q.setMaxResults(length);
     List<TableClass> tableClasslist = q.list();
     return tableClasslist;
}
```

Likewise, if you have a Criteria query, it's effectively the same thing:

```
public Long getCount(Pageable pageable) {
    Criteria c = session.createCriteria(TableClass.class);
    c.setProjection(Projections.rowCount()); 
    Long cnt = (Long) c.uniqueResult();
    return cnt;
}

public List<TableClass> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
    Criteria c = session.createCriteria(TableClass.class);
    c.setParameter("city","NY");
    c.setFirstResult(start);
    c.setMaxResults(length);
    List<TableClass> tableClasslist = c.list();
    return tableClasslist ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help. I looked for JPA solution but DataNucleus removed JPA from question's tags. I used hibernate tag to express that Hibernate is my persistance provider.