# IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException - Trying to simply get the most recent row

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-data

I have a Spring CrudRepository called 'ImportReceiptRepository'.

I'm simply trying to compose a method which grabs the first row in an order by clause.

Here's what I'm using currently:

```
ImportReceipt importReceipt = this.importReceiptRepository.getOneByImportTypeOrderByTimestampDesc(importType);
```

The issue is that when there is more than a single row returned, Spring throws a:

```
org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: result returns more than one elements; nested exception is javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: result returns more than one elements
```

How should I rename this CrudRepository function to simply grab the first row when there are 0-n rows returned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply using Pageable was the key:

```
List<ImportReceipt> findByImportType(String importType, Pageable pageable);
```

and calling it like:

```
List<ImportReceipt> importReceipts = this.importReceiptRepository.findByImportType(importType, new PageRequest(0, 1, Direction.DESC, "Timestamp"));
ImportReceipt importReceipt = importReceipts.get(0);
```

Credit: [How to combine pagination with a criteria query in Spring Data JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12782023/paging-with-condition)

Answer (score 3):

You can make it even simpler by findFirst:

```
ImportReceipt findFirstByImportType(String importType);
```

For more info: [Limiting Query Results](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result)

Answer (score 2):

As of the upcoming version 1.7 of Spring Data JPA, the query method as you originally declared it works out of the box. See [this ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-551) for details. The support has already been published in the first milestone of the release.